# How to convert a maptype into SparkML sparse vector in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

My original schema contains a lot of maptypes that I want to use in an ML model so I need to convert them into SparkML sparse vectors.

```
root
 |-- colA: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- colB: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- colC: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Context:
SparkML models require the data to be formed as a feature vector. There are
some utilities to generates the features vector but none supports the maptype type. 
e.g. 
The SparkML [VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#vectorassembler) allows to combine several columns (all numeric types, boolean type, or vector type).

**Edit**:

So far my solution is to explode the map into columns individually then use the `VectorAssembler`:

```
val listkeysColA = df.select(explode($"colA"))
  .select($"key").as[Int].distinct.collect.sorted

val exploded= df.select(listkeysColA.map(x => 
  $"colA".getItem(x).alias(x.toString)): _*).na.fill(0) 

val columnNames = exploded.columns

val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(columnNames).setOutputCol("features")
```

**Edit2**:

I should add that the data in my maps are very sparse and there is no known set of keys beforehand. That is why in my current solution I do one pass over to data first to collect and sort the keys. Then I access the values using getItem(keyName).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no in-built method for this in Spark, so an `UDF` would be a suitable solution in this case. Here is one that takes a column with a `Map[String, Double]` and returns a ML vector:

```
val toVector = udf((m: Map[String, Double]) => Vectors.dense(m.values.toArray).toSparse)
```

Since a `Map` does not have an order the resulting vector is not guaranteed to have a certain order either.

Example input (`df`):

```
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|colA                             |colB                             |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|Map(a -> 1.0, b -> 2.0, c -> 3.0)|Map(a -> 1.0, b -> 2.0, c -> 3.0)|
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

and using the `UDF`,

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("colA", toVector($"colA")).withColumn("colB", toVector($"colB"))
```

gives the following output:

```
+-------------+-------------+
|colA         |colB         |
+-------------+-------------+
|[1.0,2.0,3.0]|[1.0,2.0,3.0]|
+-------------+-------------+
```

where both columns are of vector type.

```
root
 |-- colA: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- colB: vector (nullable = true)
```

If you want to merge all the columns together into a single vector, here it would be appropriate to use a `VectorAssembler`, as in the question edit.

---

**Edit:**

If you need to keep a certain order of the values, then you need to collect all keys first as you have done. You can avoid using `explode` however:

```
val keys = df.select($"colA")
  .flatMap(_.getAs[Map[String, Int]]("colA").keys)
  .distinct
  .collect
  .sorted
```

Then change the `UDF` appropriately to take the order of `keys` into account with a default value of 0.0:

```
val toVector = udf((m: Map[String, Double]) => 
  Vectors.dense(keys.map(key => m.getOrElse(key, 0.0))).toSparse
)
```

Comment: Thanks for you elegant solution. I tried it and it work as explained.
However, I need a sparse vector as the values in my MAP are themselves sparse and the vector is to be used in an ML model so the order of feature is important.

Comment: I did try to change your udf to Sparse to match my data's requirements and I think it needs a bit of rewrite to match the Vectors.sparse definition


    (size: Int,elements: Iterable[(Integer, java.lang.Double)])org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector <and>
  (size: Int,elements: Seq[(Int, scala.Double)])org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector <and>
  (size: Int,indices: Array[Int],values: Array[scala.Double])org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector

Comment: @S.J.Clear: you can simply convert it to sparse by adding `.toSparse` at the end. I added it to the code in the answer. It's simpler since a dense vector can be created with an Array while it's not possible for the sparse counter part.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. The code does run correctly and produces a sparse vector. If I do this however due to the sparsity of my data and to the lost ordering of values from the map (as you said earlier there is no define order in the map) I cannot use it as a feature vector for ML model.

Comment: That is the reason why in my current solution I extract the list of keys, sort them, and then access the values in now defined order of keys to fill the columns.

Comment: @S.J.Clear: I must have missed that you wanted the values sorted in a specific order. I added an edit with information of what can be done in this case.